# Multiple selectors in multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, selector, nio

Is it beneficial to distribute incoming connections among n threads, each with its own independent NIO `Selector`, where n is, say, the number of cores in the server? Suppose I'm writing a server, which should handle a number of client connections. I could have something like:

```
selector.select();
Iterator<SelectionKey> i = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();

while (i.hasNext()) {
   SelectionKey key = i.next();
   i.remove();

   if (!key.isValid())
      continue;

   if (key.isAcceptable()) {
      // get one of the n selectors (I'd have one per core)
      Selector chosenSelector = getRandomSelector();

      // delegate the new connection to the chosen selector
      SocketChannel newChannel = key.channel.accept();
      newChannel.configureBlocking(false);
      newChannel.register(chosenSelector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
   }
}
```

Do you guys think this makes sense? I mean, running n threads, each with a different selector? Or should I just stick to having one single selector thread that handles OP_READ for all connections? Or maybe something else?

Comment: Preserving message order between different clients is hard enough already without deliberately making it more difficult. How are you planning on accomplishing it? Time stamps?

Comment: I guess ordering messages is an orthogonal question... Once I have received them, someone (a thread) checks the timestamps and makes sure that they are handled in the correct order, with no gaps. But I guess I'm asking something more basic here.

Answer (score 4):

No it is not beneficial, as the relation of code that needs to be processed vs. the time it takes for the IO operations is negligible. Especially if you consider the extra time you would need for the synchronization of fragmented data. It is however beneficial to have the processing of the received data done in separate threads.

So basically: have a single-threaded selector loop that copies the data from one buffer into a task-buffer for further processing in a separate thread, then launch a Runnable with that task-buffer in an Executor to process that copied data.

Comment: What if each thread would pick up the readable key, deserialize the message, and only then enqueue the deserialized objects in a single message queue for the server to handle? Assuming that such queue is in fact necessary, wouldn't a multi-threaded selection be useful?

Comment: You need to look at this from the perspective of your network card: you only have one, so threading cannot speed up reading from the one data source. In addition the main thread needs to wait till all read/write operations are performed as keys need to be finished before the next select, so no gain here either. All together you would then have a complicated solution with a speed less than single-threaded. If you want to use threading, start after `channel.read` but not before.

Comment: Since this bothered me a bit as well I did write a test program to measure what the select loop is actually doing, and the results confirm my suggestion. While at maximum load the loop was handling ~90k IOs/second, it still did only handle about 1.5 keys/select-loop. So threading the loop wouldn't do much good.

Comment: That was a nice experiment. Did you deserialize your messages in each selector-thread, or did you just hand the byte array/ByteBuffer as is to your application?

Comment: The data is copied into a task buffer in the selector thread, but the actual handling of that data is done in a background thread. So the loop is >90% busy doing the selection.

Comment: My point of parallelizing the selection was to have multiple threads, each assigned to a different set of connections. Each thread would, then, independently get incoming data and deserialize it... I agree with you that multi-threading the selection alone is kinda pointless. The idea was to have each thread doing receive+deserialize, and only then handing the received messages to the application.

Comment: The Selector model is a concept to reduce threading, as at a certain amount of threads a server spends more time on thread handling than on the actual execution. Now you probably can do what you mentioned, but then it is contradictory to the concept. And it usually does not increase speed.

Comment: High performance applications use multiple Selector Threads;  Nginx and almost every framework does this.  These Selector Threads also perform the business work inline.  Using a Executor like @TwoThe suggested is a colossal waste of resources and it introduces a whole series of problems, for example.. when Socket A read X bytes, queues task in the Executor, then reads X more bytes all before the first queued task even started.  I could write a thesis paper on why it's a bad idea to do it as suggested.

Comment: @JohnnyV what does it mean to perform business work inline? Does it mean that the SelectionKeys are not passed to threads to process and are instead processed in the iterator loop after select()?

Answer (score 3):

> Is it beneficial to distribute incoming connections among n threads, each with its own independent NIO Selector, where n is, say, the number of cores in the server?

**All major frameworks operate this way; Mina, Netty, Nginx, etc all distribute sockets across multiple selectors.  Nginx literally passes the File Descriptor to a forked process having its own selector.**

What you are describing here is the basic selector-worker model.  You have usually 2 workers per core.  Each worker has a `Selector`.  This model is absolutely necessary on Windows as each Selector can only handle 1024 sockets and the work-around that the JDK does is catastrophic for performance.

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/sun/nio/ch/WindowsSelectorImpl.java

- Core 0 - Thread -> Selector -> OP_READ/OP_WRITE -> Do Business Logic
- Core 1 - Thread -> Selector -> OP_READ/OP_WRITE -> Do Business Logic
- Core 2 - Thread -> Selector -> OP_READ/OP_WRITE -> Do Business Logic
- Core 3 - Thread -> Selector -> OP_READ/OP_WRITE -> Do Business Logic

This is the fundamental method of scaling the reactor pattern.

Its important that a single `SocketChannel` is only attached to a single `Selector`.  So don't go calling `SocketChannel.register()` to a bunch of `Selectors` and listening to **OP_READ** on all of them because you won't gain any benefit.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html

> **Q2**  Can two epoll instances wait for the same file descriptor?  If
>              so, are events reported to both epoll file descriptors?
>
> **A2**  Yes, and events would be reported to both.  However, careful
>              programming may be needed to do this correctly.

Comment: There is no such method as `SocketChannel.attach()`. There is no 'fundamental Reactor pattern' in evidence here. What is 'make smoothies'? What is the last quotation quoted from?

Comment: Yeah, it's SocketChannel.register - I edited the reply. For request response situations using this pattern can reduce cache misses substantially.   It's my understanding that both Mina and Netty work this way but I'll have to verify that later.

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly what Netty does. It uses N threads calling `Selector.select()` where N = (num available CPUs * 2) It is multiplied by 2 because of hyperthreading. This is the parent EventLoop which is considered the "acceptor eventloop" for accepting socket connections.
Then there is the child EventLoop of thread workers

Suggest you have a look at `NioEventLoopGroup`-class

Comment: Can you please put some references (github link) to "It uses N threads calling Selector.select()"?

Answer (score 0):

I would have just one selector and have it distribute the messages across a fixed number of threads through a lock-free ring buffer. Then you can have your flow in a totally lock-free, super-fast way. The flow would be like that:

Critical Selector => DEMUX => Worker Threads => MUX => Critical Selector

You just have to make sure your worker threads are enough in quantity (and you have enough free cores for them) to process your messages quickly, otherwise you can end up with a full DEMUX and the selector will have to either block or drop messages.

I suggest you read [this article](http://www.coralblocks.com/index.php/thread-concurrency-vs-network-asynchronicity/) to have an idea of how an asynchronous, single-threaded, non-blocking network framework works. Of course you can also check Netty or Mina. For an idea of the latencies you will have to pay by using the demux and the mux, which are nanoseconds, refer to [this benchmark](http://www.coralblocks.com/index.php/2014/04/coralqueue-performance-numbers/).

Comment: 'Asynchronous' and 'non-blocking' are not synonyms. You don't need them both at the same time. They refer to two distinct I/O models, blocking being a third. Java already has such a library built-in.

Comment: @EJP I did not say or think they were synonyms. I would think that asynchronous and non-blocking are two different things that go hand-in-hand. How to be asynchronous without being non-blocking? Perhaps you can clarity? I know java has `java.nio` but it is the bare bones of selectors. Then you have Netty, Mina, CoralReactor and other frameworks on top of it. By the way I edited my answer to include your suggestion to use a demux / task-buffer. I totally agree.

Comment: Your article contains nothing whatsoever to do with asynchronous I/O. 'Non-blocking' means that the operation completes or fails immediately. 'Asynchronous' means that the operation continues in the background while the actual async I/O method you called returns to your code. They are not even slightly related. Java NIO has a whole raft of asynchronous channels since I think 1.7, in addition to non-blocking and multiplexing.

Comment: @EJP Calling synchronous code blocks the current thread until said code is complete, whilst calling the same code and placing it on a thread pool would return to the caller instantly, thus not `blocking` the current thread. The distinction confuses people, though I think @rdalmeida knows what they're talking about, just conceptualizes it a little bit differently than you do.